# Json response in Grails webflow

Tags: ajax, grails, spring-webflow

Is it possible to return a json response in a Grails webflow ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering why you would?   Webflows are designed to be "wizards" where you run from page to page, finally exiting the Flow and persisting the results, or not.

You do realize you can hit non-Flow actions from WebFlow pages?  If you're writing an Ajax action for use in your Flow page, you can "render as JSON" in the action, and call the action directly using remote calls from the gsp.

Answer (score 0):

There are many use cases in which integrating Ajax with Spring WebFlow would be very handy. Unfortunately, the Spring WebFlow is doing a poor job with that regards.

The work around here is to render a GSP and append it to the section of the page you are doing the Ajax call. Remember to pass "_eventId" when you build your Ajax URL.

Answer (score 0):

I understand it is a valid case to expect JSON.

**Work around:**

Create a `.gsp` view with following content, and render it. (Of course, pass `json` string along by `flow.json = (model as JSON).toString()` !)

```
<%
    response.contentType  = 'application/json'
    response.outputStream << json.getBytes()
%>
```